# Validate GeoPackage geometries from command line

Tags: geopackage

I am trying to run ogr2ogr on two GeoPackages, but get a few errors/exceptions.

```
$ ogr2ogr out.gpkg in.gpkg -clipdst clip.gpkg
ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at 547976.04127548891 6187144.9660076108 0
ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at 547976.04127548891 6187144.9660076108 0
ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at 547976.04127548891 6187144.9660076108 0
ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at 547976.04127548891 6187144.9660076108 0
```

In any case, obviously I would like to check the validity of the gpkg files, and I would like to know exactly which features have invalid geometries. Is there a tool for that?

Comment: You appear to be using "shapefile" as a generic term for geodata. GeoPackage and shapefile as two different formats.

Comment: @Vince: Thanks for pointing out. It was simply a typo. Appologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ogrinfo with ST_IsValidReason and ST_IsValid functions. Functions come from SpatiaLite https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and are documented there.

Usage:

1. list the validity of all features

`ogrinfo -sql "select *,ST_IsValidReason(geometry) from my_layer" my_gpkg.gpkg`

2. list only invalid features

`ogrinfo -sql "select *,ST_IsValidReason(geometry) from my_layer where ST_IsValid(geometry)=false" my_gpkg.gpkg`

Notice that the name of the geometry is not necessarily "geometry". Check the name of the geometry field with ogrinfo first. Instead of `*` you can select just the attributes that you want to get. Notice that ogrinfo is placing the feature id into a special place in the output.